# How to style HTML paragraphs with CSS to prevent empty lines between them?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, paragraph

If I have 2 complete, successive paragraphs, how should I style them so that there is only one line break (so no empty line) between them?

E.g.

```
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
```

Should render as

```
First paragraph
Second paragraph
```

I am generating this HTML with XSLT.

Comment: Could you not render it without any `<p>` tags in that case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the top and bottom margins:

```
p{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally `<p>` tags will have non-zero vertical margin which gives the appearance of an "extra" line break.  You can set the paragraph margin to zero if you want no "extra" space between them.

E.g.

```
<p style="margin: 0;">First paragraph</p>
<p style="margin: 0;">Second paragraph</p>
```

Comment: I don’t think any browser has default nonzero padding for `p` elements. It’s all about vertical margins.